# The axiom of foundation and hereditarily finite sets

Tags: set-theory, axioms

I've been trying to understand the axiom of foundation, and I came up with this question, I hope it's correctly formulated.

Let $R_{i} = \left \{ i \right \}$ and $S = \left \{ R_{i} \right \}_{i\in [a,m_{0}]}$. Let $m_{n+1}=\frac{a+m_{n}}{2}$ so $m_{n+1}$ is the midpoint between $a$ and $m_{n}$ and define sets $C_{ni}$ recursively as:

$C_{1i} = \left \{ R_{i}, R_{i+m_{1}} \right \}$ for $i\in [a,m_{1}]$, and

$C_{(n+1)i} = \left \{ C_{ni}, C_{n(i+m_{n})} \right \}$ for $i\in [a,m_{n}]$

Now let $L_{a}=\left \{ C_{na}:n\in \mathbb{N} \right \}$ and define an ordering on $L$ as $C_{xa}\leq C_{ya}$ if $x\leq y$ in $\mathbb{N}$. Now define:

$C_{\omega a}= \sup_{n \in \omega } L$

Is $C_{\omega a}$ a set? I think it's not due to the axiom of foundation, but I'm not sure, hence the question.

Another question I have is: If we define an operator $\square$ recursively as:

$\square C_{1i}= \left \{ R_{i} \cup R_{i+m_{1}}\right \}$ for $i\in [a,m_{1}]$, and

$\square C_{(n+1)i}= \left \{ \square C_{ni} \cup \square C_{n(i+m_{n})}\right \}$ for $i\in [a,m_{n}]$

If $C_{\omega a}$ is a set, then does $\square C_{\omega a}=S$?

And if $C_{\omega a}$ isn't a set, does that mean that there are no hereditarily finite set s.t. the bottom of a $\in$ chain ends with all the elements of an interval of real numbers? And would this be a result of the axiom of foundation?

Comment: what does $sup$ mean in this case?

Comment: I was thinking that it would be an upper bound for $L$, but Reese's answer suggests that that would be wrong. I was thinking that it would be the same sup as with ordinals though, but then isn't there a problem with having a $\in$ chain instead of a $\subseteq$ chain?

Comment: You should put commas in the subscripts: $C_{n,i}$, not $C_{ni}$, as $ni$ usually means $n\times i.$

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your construction correctly, $C_{\omega a}$ is certainly a set. The usage of $\sup$ here is strange - I assume you just mean "union". Otherwise, $C_{\omega a}$ doesn't exist at all - there is no upper bound in $L$ of $L$.

But assuming you mean $\sup$ in the same sense as is used for ordinals - so that $\sup L$ is really the union of all of the members of $L$ - then it's still a set. It's just a set of various $C_{ni}$. Note that the "towers" in it are arbitrarily tall - there are chains of $C$'s contained in other $C$'s of greater and greater lengths - but there are no *downwards* infinite regressions. The Axiom of Foundation prohibits a situation like having $\cdots \in C_{ni_2} \in C_{ni_1} \in C_{ni_0}$, not the other way around. And no member of $C_{\omega a}$ begins such a chain.

Comment: Perhaps it's just not a well formulated construction... grrr... If $C_{ωa}$ is a set then isn't there no $C_{na}$ such that $C_{na} \in C_{ωa}$? In order to use unions wouldn't we need to have $C_{na} \subseteq  C_{ωa}$ making $C_{ωa}$ a transitive set, or something similar?

Comment: @Chickenmales Unions apply to all sets - given two sets $A$ and $B$, the union $A \cup B$ is always a set. And my interpretation of your construction *is* that $C_{na} \subseteq C_{\omega a}$, and as a consequence many of the $C$ sets are members of $C_{\omega a}$. I think you intended some sort of order-theoretic supremum for the $\sup$, rather than the union I assumed, but as I pointed out using a literal supremum doesn't make sense.